# A characterization of the Euclidean norm

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, geometry, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

Suppose that a norm $||\cdot||$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ has the following property:

Whenever norm one vectors $x$ and $y$ satisfy $||x+y||=||x-y||$ then $||x+y||=||x-y||=\sqrt{2}$.

Does it follow that $||\cdot||=||\cdot||_2$, the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

I tried to show that the parallelogram identity holds for this norm, thus implying it is Euclidean, but without success. I don't know how to deal with vectors of norm one that are not $\sqrt{2}$ apart. I expect this to be true, I would be surprised by a counterexample.

There is no source that I am aware of for this question. I am trying to understand isometric properties of Hilbert spaces, and this two dimensional version seems like a natural question to me.

Comment: Many norms satisfy the parallelogram law; namely when the unit ball is an ellipse.  Even so, it seems unlikely that this special case of the parallelogram law implies the general parallelogram law.

Comment: You are right. I guess a better question is whether the property implies the norm is a Euclidean norm, that is, is given by an inner product, not necessarily the standard inner product. Perhaps you are right, but I would like to see a en explicit definition of an nom-Euclidean norm with this property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the unit circle is a regular octagon, the norm satisfies your condition.

Comment: I see this for some $x$ and $y$ on the "unit sphere" that satisfy this property, but I don't see how you prove this for all $x$ and $y$. For any $x$ one can always find a $y$ such that the equality holds. Why is it always $\sqrt{2}$ in the distance given by the norm induced by the regular octogon?

Comment: I do not have any nice (and short) argument, why it is true, but I am very confident, that it holds. Anyway, it should be possible to check by a distinction of cases. If $x$ is on a certain side of the unit hexagon, then it should be possible to determine on which side $y$ can live.

Comment: It seems that, for every $x$, there exists exactly one $y$ with $\|x+y\|=\|x-y\|$.

Comment: I think there should be two, one on either "side" of $x$.

Comment: Yes, if $y$ works, then $-y$ works, too. I already identified antipodal points ;)

Comment: I checked for an arbitrary point on one of the sides of the octogon (and by symmetry must hold for all) , and you are right! Good intuition, thank you! Calculations are not necessarily hard, just tedious.