# A characterization of the Euclidean norm - part II

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, normed-spaces

This is a continuation of the question below.

[A characterization of the Euclidean norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4488853/a-characterization-of-the-euclidean-norm)

Suppose that a norm $||\cdot||$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ has the following property:

For any $\varepsilon\in(0,2)$ there exists $\delta\in(0,2)$ such that whenver $x$ and $y$ are norm one vectors such that $||x-y||=\varepsilon$ we have that $||x+y||=\delta$. Does it follow that $||\cdot||$ is an Euclidean norm, that is, given by an inner product on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

This is a much stronger condition than in the previous question, which was for the case $\varepsilon=\delta=\sqrt{2}$. The norm given by the regular octagon provided a counterexample for that question. For me, intuitively, the condition was too "coarse" to recover all the characteristics of the unit ball: it had information only on vectors that are $\sqrt{2}$ apart. This new condition is "finer", so it has a much better chance to be true. But I have no idea how to prove it or disprove it.

Comment: Your question is equivalent to the following: does the parallelogram identity for rhombi imply the identity for general parallelograms?

Comment: Can you please expand? I suppose that by parallelogram identity for rhombi you mean the situation when the vectors in the classical parallelogram identity are of equal norm. How does that follow from the condition in the question?